# twilio sms api special characher issue in node api

Tags: javascript, node.js, special-characters, twilio

I am sending an email address in twilio sms api.The **@** sign is not sent to the sms while other content is sent.I have to send a lot of special characters in sms which also includes alphabets of other languages like Danish language as well.

**Note:** I am using Trial account of twilio.

Here is the piece of code I am using.

```
app.get('/sendSMS' , (req , res)=> {
    twilio.messages.create({  
        from: fromNumber,   
        to: toNumber ,
        body:"abc@email.com"        
    }, (err, res) => { 
        console.log(res); 
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Following is the res

```
{ sid: 'dsfd',
  date_created: 'Sat, 28 Jan 2017 06:44:56 +0000',
  date_updated: 'Sat, 28 Jan 2017 06:44:56 +0000',
  date_sent: null,
  account_sid: ',
  to: '',
  from: '',
  messaging_service_sid: null,
  body: 'Sent from your Twilio trial account - abc@email.com',
  status: 'queued',
  num_segments: '1',
  num_media: '0',
  direction: 'outbound-api',
  api_version: '2010-04-01',
  price: null,
  price_unit: 'USD',
  error_code: null,
  error_message: null,
  uri: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/ff/Messages/ds.json',
  subresource_uris: { media: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/sdf/Messages/sdf/Media.json' },
  dateCreated: 2017-01-28T06:44:56.000Z,
  dateUpdated: 2017-01-28T06:44:56.000Z,
  dateSent: null,
  accountSid: 'dsf',
  messagingServiceSid: null,
  numSegments: '1',
  numMedia: '0',
  apiVersion: '2010-04-01',
  priceUnit: 'USD',
  errorCode: null,
  errorMessage: null,
  subresourceUris:  }
```

Instead of receving **abc@email.com** I recieved **abc email.com**

Any Insights on sending special charachters in twilio.

Comment: whats the `err`, `res` you see in your console?

Comment: @RandomUser I have added the response object.

Comment: Well you're sending the correct body, and that's intercepted by the Twilio api., Try sending the email with a special character   and check if you receive the `@` sign then. checkout this article `https://medium.com/@richard.j.hoffman/sms-twilio-and-special-characters-22f2d8918e2d#.ks20e3p95`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in article https://medium.com/@richard.j.hoffman/sms-twilio-and-special-characters-22f2d8918e2d#.7580n7ioc metioned by @RandomUser twilio requires a utf-8 charachter above a certain range in your SMS body to support unicode. so we have to add a special charachter above a certain range to support all unicode charachters in twilio sms api. I have added no break space in unicode **\u00A0** and it worked you can also add  but this will always appear in you SMS.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. That sounds wrong and you shouldn't need to force the character set like that. Could you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and supply a couple of message SIDs where the @ failed to send so that they can investigate.